ASUS R541U I want to add/replace RAM but I don't know what type of RAM to use
I have ASUS "R541U" and I want to add/replace RAM.
Task manager info --> https://prnt.sc/4cKM8BiPTBjh
I found specifications in the net:
https://www.memorystock.com/memory/ASUSR541UV.html
https://www.memorystock.com/memory/ASUSR541UJ.html
but the last letters "V" or "J" are added to the name "R541U" in those specifications.
RAM difference:
R541UV --> DDR4
R541UJ --> DDR3
How to find out which RAM without complicated disassembly (including removing the motherboard) ?
The video where one changes RAM at R541U: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqaxqQgtTZc&ab_channel=klaibase
I've trieed AIDA64 (TRIAL, Beta) for RAM inspection yet still no clear understanding:

https://prnt.sc/ShK5o6ctEUoA

https://prnt.sc/JSXBlYCbTI07



Looks like DDR4 to me. Can you post a picture of the laptop model number/serial number sticker so we can confirm it's the R541UV?

Doesn't it say "X541UJ" in one of your screenshots?

RAM Type:
DDR4
RAM Capacity:
4 GB
Maximum Memory:
16 GB
I've got the answer at another rescource: otvet.mail.ru - https://otvet.mail.ru/answer/2052359046
The answer is in Russian, yet one may apply automatic translation if needed.

DDR4 but I can't find much info that specific laptop, also looks like a lot of bad reviews, I'm going to assume its 3rd party.
Keep in mind it'll be SODIMMs DDR4 and you will have to take it apart either way to upgrade it..
